# Reading text into a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, file, multidimensional-array, filereader

I need to be able to read a text file, which then is put into an 2D array. All the questions here I've viewed use ArrayLists, which we are not allowed to. 
My text file is as shown.

```
Bananas, 5, 5
Apples, 5, 5
Steak, 5, 10
```

With the first value being the name, second quantity, and third price. I would like to place them in an array `inventory[30][3]` of 30 items, with the three traits I mentioned. I apologize if this is too basic, I tried Google and YouTube a lot and couldn't find a simple answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that I used to get an array like you want:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFileIntoArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] inventory = new String[30][3];
        try {
            File myObj = new File("filename.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            int i = 0;
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] traits = myReader.nextLine().split(",");
                for(int j = 0; j < traits.length; j++){
                    inventory[i][j] = traits[j];
                }
                i++;
            }
            // do stuff here with inventory
            myReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Couple of things to note here.

First is the split which breaks up each line of the text file on the comma. Depending on the formatting on the file you might need add in a space so as not to have trailing whitespace on the trait: `split(", ")`

The next thing is that I iterated through the `traits` string array which might be overkill since there'll only ever be 3 entries, but this means that the array can be expanded to more traits if needed in the future.

Finally the last thing is the `i` variable. This is needed to track loop iteration.